# Unable to publish the .net 5.0 and 6.0 to Azure Container Registry due to docker error

Tags: c#, azure, docker, docker-compose, nuget

I have created a Web API project and added the docker file. When I am publishing it to the Azure Container Registry I am getting the below error.

It is happening for 5.0 and 6.0 both. I have tried with VS2019 and VS2022.

Error:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.408\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\src\learndoc\learndoc.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.408\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   No such host is known. (api.nuget.org:443) [C:\src\learndoc\learndoc.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.408\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   No such host is known. [C:\src\learndoc\learndoc.csproj]
Removing intermediate container d8f9a4f724d7
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore "learndoc/learndoc.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
C:\Users\source\repos\learndocker\learndoc\Dockerfile(0,0): Error CTC1014: Docker command failed with exit code 1.

I am able to access the nuget path directly with the browser. I have tried deleting the nuget cache from appdata as well as localdata location but still not success. I have also tried restarting Visual Studio and recreating the Docker file.

Docker File Content :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY \["learndoc/learndoc.csproj", "learndoc/"\]
RUN dotnet restore "learndoc/learndoc.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/learndoc"
RUN dotnet build "learndoc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "learndoc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT \["dotnet", "learndoc.dll"\]
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using while creating web api?

Comment: Are you able to build it outside of Docker using the same `dotnet` commands? Also, you seem to have some unexpected backslashes ( \ ) in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I have used Windows Operating system

Comment: I have generated the file using visual studio. VS has added all the Docker file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with both .net 5.0 and 6.0 and able to publish in docker.

In Visual studio we have chosen the `Operating System as Linux` while creating the docker file.

The below NuGets need to installed.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
```

[image]

Used below Docker file for version 5.0.

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication7.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication7.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication7.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication7.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication7.dll"]
```

Same steps have been followed for version 6.0. and able to publish in docker.
For both the `Ports 80 and 443`.

After deploying to docker.

[image]

After deploying from Visual studio 2022 to docker hub.

[image]

> To avoid the error, check below points.

1. Try to access the NuGet package source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in your web browser to see if it is accessible.
2. If the NuGet package source is not accessible, try to use a different package source or try again later.
3. If the NuGet package source is accessible, try to clear the NuGet cache and restore the packages again.
4. If the issue persists, you can try to reinstall the .NET SDK or update it to the latest version.

Comment: I have tried all the approach but still its showing same error. Also, I am using Windows container.

Comment: I have used the [Windows Operating System](https://i.imgur.com/gfzLNi3.png) and [Windows Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVfxs.png). And able to publish successfully.